# What is the right way to update the state instantly?

Tags: reactjs

Sorry if someone has already answered this question, but I didn't find what I am looking for.

I recently started learning react and notice that there are quite a few ways to set the state. For example, I have a counter in an object, and I want to increase it.

```
const [state, setState] = React.useState({ counter: 0 });
```

And all the functions below give the same result, but as I understood, they do it asynchronously.

```
setState({ ...state, counter: counter + 1 }):

setState(() => ({ ...state, counter: counter + 1 }));

setState(prevState => ({...prevState, counter: counter + 1 }));

setState(counter = counter + 1);
```

How can I update the state instantly and properly after calling the setState function? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Why would you update the state instantly ? I guess It's a matter of using the new value ?

Comment: Can you specify your use case as to why you need to update this state instantly. setState is usually done asynchronously, as multiple setState calls are batched for performance gains. If there is any operation that you want only to happen after the state update has been done you have two solutions. You can either use setState Callback for the operation OR in case of hooks you can use the useEffect hook to achieve this.

Comment: @BikramJethi I have a project where I have a bunch of setState functions (and useEffect functions as well) and ui do not update as expected; last change always appear only after second re-render. I debugged the code using many console.log functions and found that in places where I can't use useEffect hook value do not update as needed. So, I want to try to fix this issue via requiring some setStates to update the state immediately.

Comment: A suggestion [here "from gaearon"](https://www.reddit.com/r/reactjs/comments/a3y76f/react_hooks_setstate_gotcha/ebabg32/) seems to be **rethink your code design** *if you have a bunch of setState that causes your ui to not update as expected*, my honesty.

Comment: @HuỳnhLợiNguyễn Thank you, will try to implement this!

Answer (score 1):

In order to do some logic with the newly updated value of the state, you should use

**[The UseEffect Hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html)**

```
useEffect(() => {
   /* use the new state value here */
}, [state])
```

or, **[if you're using component classes], the callback function**

```
this.setState({ ...state, counter: counter++ }, 
  () => { /* use the new state value here */  }
);
```

---

Also for a simple counter and in order not to be confused betweeen react components and react hooks...  I would recommend using the useState like this :

```
const [counter, setCounter] = React.useState(0);
setCounter(counter++);
```

Comment: Can you please explain to me or give me a link where I can see an example of the callback function? I don't understand why do I need to copy the state and modify it, and then pass a function where I modify it again.

Comment: You'll find this link useful: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate In fact you'll find that entire site useful as it details the correct way to do things in React.

Comment: @Plutonium Do you use Hooks or Class based component? If you use Hooks, you don't have the second syntax he mentioned above, [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates) is the only callback syntax in setState hook, and it works differently than what he mentioned. About the first method, it is not actually **change your state instantly**. Actually, it causes more rerender, which is harmful and should be avoided [suggested by Dan Abramov - React core team member](https://www.reddit.com/r/reactjs/comments/a3y76f/react_hooks_setstate_gotcha/ebaced5/)

Answer (score 0):

> How can I update the `state` instantly

You **can't**, because you've already declared your `state` with **`const`**, right?

```
const /*const*/ [state, setState] = React.useState({ counter: 0 });

function handleClick() {
  setState(anything)
  // you declared state with const, you "obviously" shouldn't expect this 
  // to "somehow" immediately change `state` to anything
}
```

You can only **make it work as expected** even when `state`'s updated asynchronously, or not instantly, depends on circumstances. If you want to get the newly updated value of your state to use later in a consequence, cache that new value to use is **the right way**. For example:

```
const newStateA = changeState(stateA)
setStateA(newStateA)

setStateB(calculateBFromA(newStateA)) 
// instead of
setStateB(calculateBFromA(stateA)) // will get the old value of stateA
```

Of course, you could just set `state = something` if you haven't declared it with `const`, like `let` or `var` instead, it would change `state` instantly, but it wouldn't **tell React to rerender the component later** with the newly updated state value, unless you just set it with with the "second array-destructured" param `setState` (talking about Hooks), and btw this (declare state with let/var`) is obviously **the wrong way**

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by

> How can I update the state instantly and properly after calling the setState function?

?
You actually *are updating state in the setState function*, so the question itself sound strangely.
If you want to perform some action synchronously right after new value will be set, you can use callback function, which was mentioned by [Seba99](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3636091/seba99). Here are link to docs [(basically it's setState docs)](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate). Optional callback is executed after state update, and `this.state` inside it will always be up-to-date with latest changes, you've made in `setState`.
So, if you need to synchronously get latest state and perform some actions with it (even update state one more time) - use callback of `this.setState`.